# Comparing a variable type number with an array using indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have added a `click` event listener to a button. It calls the buttons `YES` AND `NO`. Basically the `indexOf` checks if the value in the variable `foto` is in the `yesMeetup` array or in the `notMeetup` array.

I tried to debug but I always get "You got it" and it's not calling the debugger when I click on `NO` button

```
let foto = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', verify);

function verify() {
   var yesMeetup = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15];
   var notMeetup = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
   var notButton = document.getElementById('no');
   var yesButton = document.getElementById('yes');
   var decisao = document.getElementById('decisao');
   debugger;

   if (yesButton) {

        if (yesMeetup.indexOf(foto)) {
         decisao.textContent = "You got it";
      } else if (notMeetup.indexOf(foto)) {
         decisao.textContent = "wrong";
      }

   } else if (notButton) {

      if (notMeetup.indexOf(foto)) {
         decisao.textContent = "You Gou it";
      } else if (yesMeetup.indexOf(foto)) {
         decisao.textContent = "Wrong";
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: You are generating the random number *outside* the click function. In this case, the number is set in stone at runtime and will never be updated again. If you want a new random number to be generated each time a click event is fired, you need to do the assignment of the `foto` variable inside the `verify()` method. Moreover, both `yesButton` and `noButton` will return true, assuming the elements exists. What you want is to check the event target to determine which button is clicked. Like `e.target.id === 'yes'`.

Comment: `yesButton` returns an element. It will always be a `truthy` value if it exists on the DOM. It should probably be `yesButton.value`

Comment: actually this variable foto needs to get into this function gerar()  but as if I put inside it will be just on the scope of this function Idecided to put outside  function gerar(){  
       
          var score = document.getElementById('score');
          
          var fotoDOM = document.querySelector('.foto');
          fotoDOM.src = 'foto-' + foto + '.jpg';
          console.log(foto);
          document.getElementById('photo').style.animation ="appearPerson 1s";
          score.innerHTML = foto; 
          foto;
           }

Comment: but I have to get this foto variable and compare with the array inside verify(), How can but this foto variable needs to stay inside the function verify. How can I get this variable foto inside the function verify without change the number that is generating inside gerar() ??

Answer (score 4):

An `if` statement will evaluate anything passed into it as a boolean.

The only values for which it will not execute the "true" branch are all falsy values: `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `false`, `NaN`.

`Array.prototype.indexOf` returns `-1` when an element is not present in an array, which is not one of the falsy values and thus your `if` condition

```
if (array.indexOf(element))
```

will always evaluate as true.

```js
var example = [1,2,3];
if (example.indexOf(4)) {
  console.log('still true');
}
```

You can use a direct comparison to `-1`:

```js
var example = [1,2,3];
if (example.indexOf(4) !== -1) {
  console.log('this is not logged');
}
```

Or a newer, a bit cleaner, `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
var example = [1,2,3];
if (example.includes(4)) {
  console.log('this is not logged');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add click events to the buttons and check the values of the random variable. As the way you have written the code, it will always return the values for both the scenarios. Alternatively, to check the values at run time, you can use alert().